# How to keep Menu on One Line?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjBdEL
I would like that the menu at the end of the first line would show a button with a drop down menu instead of going on two lines.
When clicking on the button it should show a drop down menu contaning the "second line" menu items.

Here there's an example (Italian Wired Menu): http://www.wired.it/

```css
.menu {width:100%;}
.menu ul {
  padding:0;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  list-style:none;
}
.menu ul li {
  margin:0;
  padding:10px 20px;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:1.3em;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
    <li>Eleven</li>
    <li>Twelve</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

The Button is **not** for the responsive menu.  I need a button at **the end** of my menu to show items that does not fit into the first line of the menu.

Comment: There are tutorials all over the internet for this. Just search google. [Here is a example i found in 3 sec](http://kmturley.blogspot.com/2014/06/responsive-mobile-dropdown-navigation.html)

Comment: I think that your answer is superficial. I don't need a responsive menu button. I need a button at THE END of my menu to show items that not fit into the first line of the menu. Open the link of Wired IT and you will understand what I'm meaning.

Comment: I apologize I didn't understand your original question.

Comment: Don't worry ;) Have you got any hint for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the main menu a class, so we can easily target it in CSS and jQuery:

```
<ul class="mainmenu">
  <li>One</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Add a new `ul` to the right of the main menu:

```
<ul class="rightmenu">
  <li class="more">More ▼</li>
</ul>
```

Make the `div` container a flexbox, and make `li` inline-block for the main menu only.

When the window is resized, move all `li`s *except* the "More" `li` to the main menu.  Hide the right menu.

Then use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to find the first `li` that doesn't fit in the main menu, and move it, its previous sibling, and all its next siblings to the right menu.  Then show the right menu:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.menu li:not(.more)').appendTo('.mainmenu');

    $('.rightmenu').hide();

    $('.mainmenu li').each(function() {
      if(this.getBoundingClientRect().right > this.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().right) {
        $(this).prev().nextAll().addBack().appendTo('.rightmenu');
      }
    });

    $('.rightmenu').toggle($('.rightmenu').children().length>1);
  }, 10);
}).resize();
```

Use `setTimeout()` so the function won't run constantly while resizing.

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWOjmV)

**Snippet**

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.menu li:not(.more)').appendTo('.mainmenu');
    
    $('.rightmenu').hide();
    
    $('.mainmenu li').each(function() {
      if(this.getBoundingClientRect().right > this.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().right) {
        $(this).prev().nextAll().addBack().appendTo('.rightmenu');
      }
    });
    
    $('.rightmenu').toggle($('.rightmenu').children().length>1);
  }, 10);
}).resize();
```

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
}
.menu ul {
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu li {
  margin:0;
  padding:10px 20px;
  position:relative;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:1.3em;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.mainmenu {
  flex: 1;
}

.mainmenu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.rightmenu {
  width: 7em;
  height: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rightmenu:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="rightmenu">
    <li class="more">More ▼</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a way to hide "More ▼" if all <li> elements are on the main menu? By the way thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The way wired has their site setup is that the 'more' dropdown items are shown based on viewport width.

For instance from a window width of 650px to 800px, the 'more' section has 5 navagation items in it.
800px to 1000px has 2 navagation items in 'more'

I setup a code to help you understand what is going on.

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li class="hide-sml">Ten</li>
    <li class="hide-sml">Eleven</li>
    <li class="hide-sml">Twelve</li>
      <li class="more-li">MORE
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>Ten</li>
           <li>Eleven</li>
            <li>Twelve</li>
        </li>  
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu {width:100%;}
.menu ul {
  padding:0;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  list-style:none;
}
.menu ul li {
  margin:0;
  padding:10px 20px;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:1.3em;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;
  position:relative;
}
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
li ul.dropdown{
    width: 150px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
li ul.dropdown li{
    width: 100%;
    background:#333;
    color: #fff;
    cursor:pointer;
}
ul li.more-li{
    display:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
@media screen and (max-width:700px) {
    ul li.hide-sml{
        display:none;
    }
    ul li.more-li{
        display:inline-block;
    }

}
```

JQUERY

```
$('ul li.more-li').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.dropdown').toggle();
});
```

Here is the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9L087q04/).

Let me know if you have any questions about the code.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. But I prefer the Ritch Hitchcock's solution because is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
**<!-- css code -->**
    <style>
    .menu {width:100%;}
    .menu ul {
      padding:0;
      float:left;
      width:100%;
      list-style:none;
    }
    .menu ul li {
      margin:0;
      **padding:10px 15px;**
      position:relative;
      display: inline-block;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      font-size:1.3em;
      font-weight:bold;
      font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;
    }

    .menu  ul.dropdown-menu li {
      margin:0;
      padding:10px 15px;
      position:relative;
      display: block;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      font-size:1.3em;
      font-weight:bold;
      font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;

    }
    </style>

**<!-- html code -->**
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
        <li>Six</li>
        <li>Seven</li>
        <li>Eight</li>
        <li>Nine</li>
        <li>Ten</li>
        <li>Eleven</li>
        <li>Twelve</li>
        **<a  href="#" id="submenu">more </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="more" style="margin-left: 81%">
                            <li><a href="#asas">Video</a></li><li><a href="#asas">Gallery</a>**</li>                  </ul>
    </div>

**<!-- js code to show and hide menu on selecting button -->**
    <script>
    $('.dropdown-menu').css('display' , 'none');
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submenu').click(function() {
                $('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle("fast");
        });
    }); 
    </script>
```

The highlighted lines are edited from my side. Hope this will help you.

Thanks.